# Rally .NET REST: How to create new Test Case Results

Tags: c#, rest, rally

Ok - sorry for the lack of specificity in my original question. Here is what I am trying to do - update Rally with a Test Case Result for a specific browser Test Case. A snippet of the update code:

```
    DynamicJsonObject newTestCaseResult = new DynamicJsonObject();

    newTestCaseResult["Date"] = "2012-04-25";
    newTestCaseResult["TestCase"] = "TC1234";
    newTestCaseResult["Notes"] = "XSLT support tests";
    newTestCaseResult["Build"] = "20120430.3681";
    newTestCaseResult["Verdict"] = "Pass";

    // Create the TestCaseResult
    CreateResult cr = restApi.Create("TestCaseResult", newTestCaseResult);
```

I'm getting this exception on the create step:

```
           {System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.}
```

Any idea as to where I'm going wrong? Does this question meet the need for improved specificity?

Comment: Rally's developers are working on a .NET REST starter kit, but until that's available it may be worth making a focused inquiry either here or with Rally support (rallysupport@rallydev.com) who could help out with a specific example or two.

Comment: While it is closed I cannot even answer it. I think there was a case where some WSAPI errors would return that exception instead of something more clear. If you downloaded the C# toolkit before the last few days I would make sure to get the current one from developer.rallydev.com

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the error message Charles - that's good to know. One thing I'm noticing - assigning a FormatteID string probably won't do the trick, - I believe that the assignment of TestCase needs to be a reference in the form of newTestCaseResult["TestCase"] = "/testcase/12345678"; where the long int is the OID of the Test Case of concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

noting that this question has been re-opened, you may wish to adjust your assignment of a TestCase to use a reference instead of a FormattedID, per my comment in the comments section:

```
    newTestCaseResult["TestCase"] = "/testcase/12345678";
```

where the long int is the OID of the Test Case of concern.

Comment: Thanks for re-opening my Question. Yep - this was the tip I needed, i.e.e the reference rather than the FormattedID. I also downloaded the 1.07 dll, which gives me the somewhat more informative but still slightly cryptic: {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.} on the call to update().